# Link the folder in LAMP server

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

How to link multiple folders in LAMP website

I'm trying configure [NPTEL](http://nptel.ac.in/Harddisk/local_server.php) application in local machine

```
command:

#ln -s /nptel/NPTEL/Phase*/1* /var/www/html/NPTEL 
#ln -s /nptel/NPTEL/*/*/1* /var/www/html/NPTEL 
#ln -s /nptel1/NPTEL/Phase*/1* /var/www/html/NPTEL
```

all help is much appreciated